# Nodemcu is connected to 5v relay with logic converter but still not working

Tags: nodemcu, electronics, electricity

I am using a bi-directional 3.3-5V logic converter to control 5V relay with 3.3V D5 pin of nodemcu. link of logic  converter is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUeVv.png)

However, I expected to control the relay but it didn't work. I don't think there is a problem with electrical connection or code since that is simple.

3.3V sides of nodemcu is connected to LV and 5V side of Relay is connected to HV.

Code:-

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(D5, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
digitalWrite(D5, HIGH);
delay(2000);
digitalWrite(D5, LOW);
delay(2000);
}
```

My Observations:-
1) When relay is removed, multimeter shows 3.3V at the LV & HV side. (so logic converter is not working i guess)
2) When relay  is  connected, multimeter shows 2.5V on  both sides.

Everything is powered from nodemcu pins. Does  it means that i have to supply extenal power or something wrong with logic converter?[![enter image description here][2]][2]

What do you guys think?

PS  - I  soldered the pins another way around on logic converter. Does it change anything?

circuit image, nodemcu is powered by the laptop USB

[image: circuit]

Comment: Please show your actual wiring.

Comment: Are you trying to drive a pure relay, or do you have a relay module (which already includes the driver circuit). If the first, make sure, that the level converter can actually provide the needed current

Comment: The photograph you provide is not helpful. Instead, show us the schematic of your actual circuit and provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the level converter **and** the relay.

Comment: Its the relay module that I am running. I provided  that above photo to check if I  soldered right side. Will the logic converter work if I soldered behind? will  add  the  circuit  also

Comment: can anybody draw wiring diagram for raspberry pi to relay connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must supply a steady, regulated voltage to both 3.3v and 5v pins at all time (see Voltage Inputs on https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide/all).

Logic level controller does NOT convert 3.3v to 5v for powering the relay, it just let you turn 3.3v signal to 5v so a relay can get activated. Relay's positive pin still needs to be supplied with a 5v from a PSU or other sources.

Answer (score 1):

To make that work you'd need to connect the HV connection to the Vin of the NodeMCU (as well as to the relay board) which should be the 5 V coming form the USB port. You'd also need to connect the GND on the HV side to the GND of the NodeMCU.

Comment: Exactly. Although the GND sides are probably connected, the 5V needed for the relay and logic conversion needs to be supplied from somewhere. It will not be generated by the logic level converter.

Answer (score 0):

The converter and/or the nodemcu can't provide enough current to drive the relay. So you should get a 5V psu.
For further details we need more information about the parts you use.

Comment: could be, I put arduino instead of nodemcu  since it has 5V pins and worked